# Is it proper to teach Dhamma to someone wearing a hat?

Tags: sila, refuge, veneration

or when wearing one oneself?

(The question might be worthy to copy also in your meta-section... for possible increase of general respect toward the Gems and enviroment for providing such, since else might cause harm for many althought not aware for now.)

Answer (score 3):

The following rules are part of the Sekhiya rules of the [Patimokkha](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/sv/bhikkhu-pati.html). The Patimokkha are rules for (Theravada) monks and nuns.

> 66. I will not teach Dhamma to a person wearing headgear who is not ill: a training to be observed.
> 67. I will not teach Dhamma to a person whose head is covered (with a robe or scarf) and who is not ill: a training to be observed.

The explanation for these come in "[The Bhikkhus' Rules: A Guide for Laypeople](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html)" by Bhikkhu Ariyesako:

> Sixteen of the Sekhiya Training rules set down how and to whom a
>   bhikkhu should teach Dhamma. These rules are also concerned with the
>   etiquette of showing respect, respect not only for the bhikkhu but
>   more importantly for the Dhamma that he is teaching. ([The Great
>   Standards](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html#modern) would imply here that modern ways of showing respect and
>   disrespect would be similarly covered by these rules.) These rules
>   prohibit a bhikkhu from teaching anyone he considers to be showing
>   disrespect to the Dhamma. Here is a summary of these Sekhiya
>   Trainings:
>
> > "I will not teach Dhamma to someone who is not sick but who:
> >
> > — has an umbrella; a wooden stick (club); weapon in their hand.
> >
> > — is wearing (wooden-soled) sandals/shoes; is in a vehicle; is on a
> >     bed (or couch); is sitting clasping the knees; has a head wrapping
> >     (turban); whose head is covered; who is sitting on a seat while I am
> >     sitting on the ground; who is sitting on a high seat while I am
> >     sitting on a low seat; who is sitting while I am standing; who is
> >     walking in front of me while I am walking behind; who is walking on a
> >     pathway while I am walking beside the pathway." (Sekhiya 57-72; See
> >     BMC pp.505-508)
>
> How these rules are observed may diverge in different communities.
>   **Some will strictly follow the above while others will be more flexible
>   according to modern conditions**. As Venerable Brahmava"ngso remarks:
>
> > "...These Sekhiyas ensure that one teaches Dhamma only to an audience
> >     which shows respect. One may not expound from a soapbox in the
> >     marketplace... to the indifference of passers by. However it is common
> >     these days in the West for a seated audience, wearing their shoes and
> >     maybe even a hat, to respectfully listen to a speaker standing at a
> >     lectern... and **as the audience is considered to be behaving
> >     respectfully according to the prevailing norms there seems no reason
> >     why a monk may not teach Dhamma in such a situation**." (AB)

Comment: Good to quote what was given by the Buddha and long time preserved by his courageously and faithful Sangha.