# Xin Ling Fa Men 心灵法门 - Little House

Tags: chinese-buddhism

Master Lu ("New" Buddhism) most famous method of healing which is burning little house which i believe forbidden by Buddhism. [Little House](https://www.videosworthsharing.com/guanyincitta/introduction-to-little-house/)

There are many psychologies study supporting that burning negative thought can have some form of mental issue healing. I do that sometime but not little house.
[Burning Letter and Letting Go](https://bestselfmedia.com/burning-letters-letting-go/)

Q) May i know where is the Sutta written that this is forbidden ?

Related post - [Xin Lin Fa Men](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/xin-lin-fa-men-%E5%BF%83%E7%81%B5%E6%B3%95%E9%97%A8-new-buddhism)

> Learning Buddhism is to Change Destiny

[Xin Ling Fa Men Branches](https://xinlingfamen.info/?hl=en)

Comment: Hmmm... Xin Lin Fa Men is a little known group, and from your recent spate of questions seems problematic. I'm beginning to believe that you are either trying to defame this group or draw attention to it (or both). Is that the case?

Comment: @Ted Wrigley yes, i would like to know Master Lu teaching can be used for emergency used as described by Doc.  https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/46116/xin-lin-fa-men-%E5%BF%83%E7%81%B5%E6%B3%95%E9%97%A8-new-buddhism

Comment: it's not little known group. it has 10 M members around the world - https://xinlingfamen.info/contact/?go=review&hl=id   guess my country has < 1k true Buddhist https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41208/why-there-is-limited-sharing-in-buddhism

Comment: @TedWrigley The organisation presence is deemed illegal in mainland China, but it appears they still hold some influence in overseas Chinese communities. I'd say they are moderately well-known.

Comment: @viptrongproz98 Master Lu just passed away, do u know what happen? Let's continue on the chat if you want.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131335/discussion-on-question-by-little-star-xin-lin-fa-men--little-house).

Comment: @littlestar: My apologies. 10 million followers is indeed significant (though in the modern world by no means large). It must not have made many inroads in my part of the US.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "burning house", one finds this:

> [Thag16.1:8.1](https://suttacentral.net/thag16.1/en/sujato#thag16.1:8.1): Having realized the supreme Dhamma,
> [Thag16.1:8.2](https://suttacentral.net/thag16.1/en/sujato#thag16.1:8.2): without needing anything in the whole world,
> [Thag16.1:8.3](https://suttacentral.net/thag16.1/en/sujato#thag16.1:8.3): one doesn’t grieve at death;
> [Thag16.1:8.4](https://suttacentral.net/thag16.1/en/sujato#thag16.1:8.4): for it’s like **escaping from a burning house**.

Although interesting as a quote, it may seem far from your question.  However, if one thinks of burning little houses as an "observance", then the Buddha does indeed speak quite clearly about misapprehension of precepts and observances. It is a lower fetter.

> [MN64:5.10](https://suttacentral.net/mn64/en/sujato#mn64:5.10): That misapprehension of precepts and observances is reinforced in them, not eliminated: it is a lower fetter.

Consider a person who shoplifts, which is stealing. If they burn a little house every time they shoplift, is the harm done to the shopkeeper taken away? How could this burning of a little house help? That shoplifter is bound by a lower fetter.

On the other hand, consider a person who grieves for a beloved one, missing a smile or caring glance. If that person burns a little house thinking, "This grief is not mine, I am not this grief, this grief is not my self", it may help.

> [MN62:8.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn62/en/sujato#mn62:8.5): This should be truly seen with right understanding like this: ‘This is not mine, I am not this, this is not my self.’

Taken together, these two examples show us that we need to be careful about becoming attached to the burning of little houses, especially if we think, "the burning of little houses is mine."

Perhaps one might ask if burning the little house is escaping the burning house or clinging to it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if little Red abounds the circles of "Show masters", starts to investigate what the Sublime Buddha taught, and possible finds Refuge in the Gems.

While such wouldn't work by aversion, even by burning things, good to inwardly burn away defilements by ways of gratitude as only such would give release toward higher.